# How import java class from library java in code java

Tags: java, shared-libraries, lotus-domino

For explain situation I was in Lotus Designer.
I works with java class and I would like add code from java Library and I can't.
My library are in the Script's Libraries but I can't import this class of my Library !!

I don't understand !!

exemple :

```
Code => Script's Libraries => com.pasquier.utilitaire.UtiliRepertoire;
     => java's code => package com.pasquier.photoWeb.DAO;

package com.pasquier.photoWeb.DAO;

import com.pasquier.utilitaire.UtilRepertoire; <=   "import can not be resolved"

public class PhotoDAO {


}
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: It's look like jar missing from build path.

Comment: try using classpath while compiling

Comment: UtiliRepertoire is the class you want to import? If its not in the same package ckeck if the class its defined as public

Comment: I already use the code of my Library in other (in web service providers with success), so the classpath is ok, isn't it ?

Comment: All the classes are public but there are in a Library (in designer lotus there are possibilities to make Library lotus or java and to share it in other code).

Comment: the import seems legit. If you have the jar of the code you want to import try adding it right clicking on project, properties, library- add the library.

Comment: I had PhotoWeb.ntf/Code/ScriptLibraries in the buildpath but it's same

Comment: I can't add the Library on the project like you say ( I do that when I have a web service but in the code\java, I can't or I don't know where I do that ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it isn't possible to access the libraries from the code java.
We must copy the package in Library ANd in the code...